# "Set Datasource Location" results in inescapable looping of DB login prompt

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Here's the situation: I receive reports written by a vendor which are all developed on their own Oracle DB. Normally, there is no issue in setting a new datasource to our own Oracle DB, but this one report in particular is not playing nicely.

The report in question has 8 SQL Expressions, and a subreport with an additional 3 SQL Expressions (I mention this because I suspect this may have something to do with it, but not sure. Almost like CR is attempting to verify the SQL Expressions on the old DB). I'm able to update the data source of the subreport just fine, but when I try it with the main report, Crystal prompts me repeatedly for the login to the OLD DB where the report was developed (which I obviously do not have access to). The prompt is inescapable and I have to terminate Crystal's process each time.

I've tried unchecking all report and database checking/verification options in CR to no avail. If anyone has any advice as to what I could try next, it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Well, it looks like all I had to do is close the login window a BILLION times (OK, more like ~16, twice for each SQL Expression?). Leaving the question open, though, to see if there is any way to avoid having to go through this for future reports.

EDIT EDIT: Some more details. This is still happening with CR 2008 SP3 attempting to connect to an Oracle 11g database with 11g R2 client. I'm not sure about how these reports were developed, but it was with CR XI at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this w/ migrated reports before, but it's been loong ago.

If you had to do it a million times, I would have guessed that you actually had 999,999 sub-reports -- all to the same old data source, all needing verification or failure to try the new data source.  Sorry, I just re-read... I meant to put 'a BILLION' minus 1.

Did you check your TNSNames against (whatever config supplied by the vendor)?

Are you using the same driver used by the vendor Oracle reports?  (Oracle driver vs MS ODBC for Oracle vs CR ODBC for Oracle vs MyPrettyPony ODBC Dri...)

Did you go through the Set DataSource exercise in CR?

Can you save the subreports seperately and run them individually w/out needing the (insert some large number) login window closures?

Can you create a new report, set to your own Oracle data source?  (I have to assume this one is ok, based on your comments)

If you copy the Show SQL Query and use that as a Command query in a new report, does that run?  (Rinse and repeat as sub-reports).

(I'm stalling for time as I search my memory for the last time I experienced the same...)

Comment: In the name of Science, I started the whole process over. This time I removed the single subreport entirely. When I tried updating the data source for the main report, I had to click the Cancel button exactly 20 times (to illustrate why I'm trying to avoid having to do this in the future; it took anywhere between 4 and 25 seconds between clicks).

The report works fine afterwards, with and without the subreport (I did not try to create a command, though). Let's see... everything else you listed above is fine.

Comment: "Stop in the name of SCIENCE!"  As long as it's working for you, it's all good.  I chalk it up to "if I walk away for a bit, I'll bet that it'll run next time I try it!"  I get that a lot.  Dang, now I've got "She blinded me with Science!" running through my brain... could be worse, my brain could have been Rick Rolled!